Is it posible to click an image and then execute javascript in a pdf document created with tcpdf?
I'm creating a PDF document with Laravel and TCPDF (elibyy/tcpdf-laravel).
I want to show/hide a layer when clicking an image.
I can do that by clicking on a button because the Button() method has a parameter called $link where I can put javascript code (or a URL).
The Image() and Link() methods have the same parameter too but in that case, you can't call javascript (only a URL).
Button() example (show an alert)
$pdf_doc->Button('name', $w, $h, '', 'app.alert();'); // works

Image() example:
$pdf_doc->Image($image_url, $x, $y, $w, $h, $type, 'app.alert();') // doesn't work

Is there a workaround to achieve that?

K J, the requirement is to create a PDF report where a pseudo map shows clickable points. When the user clicks a point detailed information will be displayed. Showing and hiding layers is the only way I found to do that. Is there another?

This report is for internal use and we don't have any problem using only Acrobat for viewing the result.
In your RPG example, Did you mean to click a link to show another page (Details page), and then click a close button to go to the previous page?
Using a comment pop-out, Could I put an image inside it?

Did you try this - using the Button() method to simulate an image that triggers JavaScript?
For example, first create an image
$img = $pdf_doc->ImageSVG($prop, $prop, .... );

And using this image to create/simulate a button that executes your js code,
$pdf_doc->Button($action=yourjscode,$prop=array('image' => $img));

I didn't mention all the arguments. I think you can find it in the documentation. I just wanted to show you an idea of how you can try this.
